# Imprimir variable en html

Tags: php, html, mysql, string, variables

quisiera imprimir una variable dentro de un html, el problema que este html viene desde la base de datos, por lo tanto esta dentro de un string, hay alguna forma de hacer que php detecte que hay variables dentro de ese string que se trae de la DB?

Cualquier cosa es de ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de como viene de la base de datos para poder ayudarte!

Comment: No se si entendí la pregunta bien pero visualice esta respuesta. Puedes probar utilizando [https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php), pero te recomiendo si los datos son ingresados desde un formulario que escapes los datos o seas muy metódico con la seguridad porque es una vulnerabilidad que tu sistema reciba código ejecutable y que pueda ser ejecutado casí sin supervisión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `str_replace`, si dentro del HTML viene la variable `$nombre`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
str_replace("$nombre", "nuevo valor", $tu_html);
```